# python download all files in a web page

Tags: python

I am running below code to download all files in a webpage:

```
import os
import urllib
from lxml import html

def main():
    os.chdir("Downloads/")
    url = "http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_IEC_14496-26_2010_Bitstreams/DVD1/mpeg4audio-conformance/compressedMp4/"

    page = html.fromstring(urllib.urlopen(url).read())

    for link in page.xpath("//a"):
        filelink = "http://standards.iso.org/" + link.get("href")
        print "download",filelink
        runme("wget " + filelink)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But I guess it's not the best one, how can I improve it with less code lines?

Comment: Add code to use the url to extract the hostname, don't hardcode it.

Comment: If your sole goal is to have less lines, there isn't much else beside maybe using some more modern libraries to aid the work like `python-requests` and `BeautifulSoup 4` or even some full toolset like `Scrapy`. However if you want to have this optimized for speed and/or less error, then first thing I would ask is whether your `runme` is asynchronously executed, and whether it handles when `filelink` is a malformed link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use *urljoin* to join the url and you can use just the xpath to get the hrefs, you don't need to call find:

```
import urllib
from lxml import html
from urlparse  import urljoin
def main():
    url = "http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_IEC_14496-26_2010_Bitstreams/DVD1/mpeg4audio-conformance/compressedMp4/"

    page = html.fromstring(urllib.urlopen(url).read())

    for link in page.xpath("//a/@href"):
        runme("wget " + urljoin("http://standards.iso.org/", link))
```

Apart from that I would prefer to use requests.

If you want to make  asynchronous you could utilise the [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) lib:

```
import os
import urllib
from lxml import html
from urlparse  import urljoin
import grequests

def main():
    url = "http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_IEC_14496-26_2010_Bitstreams/DVD1/mpeg4audio-conformance/compressedMp4/"

    page = html.fromstring(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
    reqs = (grequests.get((urljoin("http://standards.iso.org/", link))) for link in page.xpath("//a/@href"))
    for resp in grequests.imap(reqs):
        print(resp.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a better question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). In short, your code is fine. If anything, you might want to use more lines. Here's my attempt at cleaning it up some... but I've added lines.

```
import os

from urllib import urlopen, basejoin
from lxml import html

def main():
    os.chdir('Downloads')

    base_url = 'http://standards.iso.org'
    page_url = basejoin(base_url, 
                'ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/'
                'ISO_IEC_14496-26_2010_Bitstreams/'
                'DVD1/mpeg4audio-conformance/compressedMp4/')

    page_string = urlopen(page_url).read()
    page_html = html.fromstring(page_string)

    for link in page_html.getiterator('a'):
        file_url = basejoin(base_url,  link.get('href'))

        if file_url.endswith('.mp4'):
            print 'Downloading: {}'.format(file_url)
            runme('wget {}'.format(file_url))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If we break this function down, we can see that you need to do a few things:

1. Send a request to get the contents of a webpage.
2. Parse the response as HTML.
3. Search the resulting tree for "a" tags.
4. Construct the full file path from the "a" tag's `href` attribute.
5. Download the file at that location.

I'm not aware of any module that will combine some of these steps. Your code is relatively readable and I don't see any inefficiencies. In summary, I think the biggest mistake is thinking that using less lines would improve your code (at least in this case).